# Dictionary file crashing but compiling fine

Tags: c, dictionary

Hi guys I am trying to implement a spellchecker for some coursework but I am new to C and just loading the dictionary file is ruining my head. The following code compiles fine, but crashes when its running. Sometimes after printing 500 lines sometimes 1500 but I have no idea what could be causing it!

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 

{
FILE *words_ptr;    //pointer for words.txt

char new_word[100];
char temp_word[100];
char *dict[45440];
words_ptr = fopen( "dictionary.txt", "r" );
if(words_ptr != NULL )
{
    printf( "File dictionary.txt opened\n");
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(temp_word, 45440, words_ptr)) 
    {
        new_word[i] = (char)calloc(strlen(temp_word), sizeof(char)); //ensuring new_word will be the right size
        strcpy(new_word, temp_word);     //copy contents of temp_word to   new_word
        dict[i] = new_word;               //copy contents of new_word to i'th element of dict array
        printf("printing out dict[%d]: %s\n", i, dict[i]); 
        i++;
    }  
    printf("printing out dictionary1: %s\n", dict[1]);

    fclose( words_ptr );
    return 0;
}
else {printf( "Unable to open file words.txt\n" ); return 1;}

}
```

Comment: *new_word[i] = (char)calloc(strlen(temp_word), sizeof(char)); //ensuring new_word will be the right size*  Not quote correct.  `new_word` is one byte too small - you forgot room for the terminating `'\0'` character.

Comment: Note: don't cast the result of `calloc` & friends or `void *` in general in C.

Comment: `fgets(temp_word, 45440, words_ptr)` → `fgets(temp_word, 100, words_ptr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
new_word[i] = (char)calloc(strlen(temp_word), sizeof(char)); //ensuring new_word will be the right size
```

does not provide sufficient space to copy the string.  It's one byte too short as `strlen()` does not include the terminating `'\0'` character.

Also, `new_word` only has space for 100 `char` entries - it's not even a `char *`.  It's completely extraneous.  Just save the result of `calloc()` directly to `dict[i]`:

```
dict[i] = strdup( temp_word );
```

And yes, there's a function called `strdup()` the duplicates a string.  [It's been part of the POSIX standard for about 16 years.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html)

Comment: You are champions thanks. I put dict[i] = strdup( temp_word ); straight in there and it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

According to the man page, *The calloc() function allocates memory for an array of `nmemb` (first argument) elements of `size` (second argument) bytes each and returns a pointer to the  allocated  memory. The  memory is set to zero.*

You are basically casting a pointer to char and further assigning it to a char, which makes no sense. Instead of declaring `new_word` as a char array, make it `char *` and do `calloc` like this:

```
char *new_word;
...
new_word = calloc(strlen(temp_word) + 1, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Nice catch.  That one's hard to spot.